# How to use scala.collection.immutable.List in a Java code

Tags: java, performance, list, scala

I need to write a code that compares performance of Java's `ArrayList` with Scala's `List`. I am having a hard time getting the Scala `List` working in my Java code. Can some one post a real simple "hello world" example of how to create a Scala `List` in java code (in a `.java` file) and add say 100 random numbers to it?

PS: I am quite good at Java but have never used Scala.

Comment: I guess you can write a Scala code that uses Java ArrayList compile and execute to compare... after-all both will run on JVM. I am unsure if it's possible to import Scala list in Java. But I am a Scala n00b. Possibly wrong.

Comment: The Scala equivalent of java.util.List is collection.mutable.Buffer.

Comment: What kind of tests ? What scenarios ? Which algorithms ? Scala Lists are immutable by default and are supposed to be used with functional programming patterns. It make no sense using them from Java. You can try `ArrayBuffer` which is very similar to Scala `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Nishant: using scala is not an option for me. because i am comparing some other libraries in java too. and especially because its kind of a home work problem and java is enforced.

Comment: So your homework is compairing apples and pears? Then I'd suggest benching ArryList vs. scala Vector instead.

Comment: So, is this an exceptionally dumb homework assignment, or an exceptionally clever one?

Comment: The answer by @simbo1905 worked best for me!

Comment: Well, if you have scala library onboard, the easiest way from my point of view is scala.collection.JavaConverters
```lang-java
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;

object Test extends App {
  java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add("abc");
  scala.collection.immutable.List<String> scalaList = JavaConverters.collectionAsScalaIterable(list).toList();
}. 
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's easier to use Java collections in Scala than the other way around, but since you asked:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.*;

public class foo {
  public List test() {
    List nil = Nil$.MODULE$; // the empty list
    $colon$colon one = $colon$colon$.MODULE$.apply((Integer) 1, nil); // 1::nil
    $colon$colon two = $colon$colon$.MODULE$.apply((Integer) 2, one); // 2::1::nil
    System.out.println(one);
    System.out.println(two);
    return two;
  }
}
```

This compiles with javac with scala-library.jar in the classpath:

```
javac -classpath /opt/local/share/scala-2.9/lib/scala-library.jar foo.java
```

You can invoke from the Scala REPL:

```
scala> (new foo).test
List(1)
List(2, 1)
res0: List[Any] = List(2, 1)
```

To use a Java collection from Scala, you don't have to do anything special:

```
scala> new java.util.ArrayList[Int]
res1: java.util.ArrayList[Int] = []

scala> res1.add(1)
res2: Boolean = true

scala> res1
res3: java.util.ArrayList[Int] = [1]
```

Comment: Thanks naten, I have to stick to java. the code you posted for java , i have a few questions. The code looks a bit odd especially the " $colon$colon" is there somewhere i can read about it? Question 2: are 'one' and 'two ' lists?  i am a bit confused can you please explain what exactly the two lines after you create an empty list mean? thanks

Comment: $colon$colon is the :: class in Scala.  $colon$colon$.MODULE$ is the :: companion object.  The "one" line is just a translation into Java of the bytecode generated for 1::nil, which could be written ::.apply(1, nil).  If you want to know how Scala code is compiled, run javap on the output.

Comment: @Shaunak. You should really spend some time reading about scala lists if you want to use them. See step 9 here: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/steps.html

Comment: @naten You could have written `nil.$colon$colon((Integer) 1)` and `one.$colon$colon((Integer) 2)` instead of calling the companion object. With the added benefit that it would be what your comment says it is. :-)

Comment: @Daniel Thanks.  I forgot that :: was both a subclass of List and a method.  I was compiling to bytecode in my head :-)

Answer (score 24):

Use scala.collection.JavaConversions from inside of java.

For example to create a nested scala case class that requires a scala List in its constructor:

```
case class CardDrawn(player: Long, card: Int) 
case class CardSet(cards: List[CardDrawn])
```

From Java you can use asScalaBuffer(x).toList() as follows:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public CardSet buildCardSet(Set<Widget> widgets) { 

  List<CardDrawn> cardObjects = new ArrayList<>();

  for( Widget t : widgets ) {
    CardDrawn cd = new CardDrawn(t.player, t.card);
    cardObjects.add(cd);   
  }

  CardSet cs = new CardSet(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(cardObjects).toList());
  return cs;
}
```

Comment: This answer seems quite a bit better than the other ones posted here, maybe because it's posted 2 years later. I'm not sure why it's not getting more attention. Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: I promote this answer, too!

Answer (score 13):

What an horrible comparison! I'll leave it to others to explain how to accomplish what you want, but here's a few reasons why this shouldn't even be tried:

1. Scala's `List` is a persistent, immutable collection, `ArrayList` is a mutable collection;

   1. That means `ArrayList` must be copied before passed to methods that may change it, if the content must be preserved, while no such thing is necessary with `List`;
   2. It also mean that `ArrayList` support operations not possible in `List`;
2. `List` has constant-time prepend, `ArrayList` has amortized constant-time append. Both have linear time the other operation.
3. `ArrayList` has constant-time indexed access, `List` has linear time indexed access, which is not the intended mode of use anyway;
4. `List` should be used through self-traversing methods, such as `foreach`, `map` and `filter`, which use closures, `ArrayList` is externally traversed through an iterator or index.

So, basically, each suck at the other's efficient operations, and the very algorithms used with one shouldn't be used with the other. Let's consider the very benchmark you propose:

> create a scala List and add say 100
>   random numbers to it

You don't add elements to a Scala `List` -- it is immutable. You create a new `List` based on an existing `List` and a new element. In the end, you'll have 100 different lists (of sizes 1 to 100), all of which can be used without changing the other. Meanwhile, if you add 100 elements to an `ArrayList`, you'll have one `ArrayList` of size 100. So, whatever the time difference is, each operation did something different.

**Edit**

I'm posting here a slightly different version of naten's code, which uses a method on `List` itself to prepend an element, instead of calling a factory.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.*;

public class Foo {
  public List test() {
    List nil = Nil$.MODULE$; // the empty list
    List one = nil.$colon$colon((Integer) 1); // 1::nil
    List two = one.$colon$colon((Integer) 2); // 2::1::nil
    System.out.println(one);
    System.out.println(two);
    return two;
  }
}
```

And, in answer to your question to him, `$colon$colon` is how Scala represents the method `::` in the JVM, that being the method used to prepend elements. Also, that method binds to the right instead of the left, reflecting the nature of the operation, which is why the comment is `1::nil` instead of `nil::1`.

The empty list, `Nil$.MODULE$`, is referenced instead of created anew because it's a singleton -- there's no way to create an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest route would be to start with a java interface and implement that in scala. For example create a java.util.List-implementation around the scala list in scala. Typically like this:

```
class ScalaList[T](val ts: T*) extends java.util.List[T] {

  // Add all the methods, but implement only the neccessary ones
  // Add all ts

}
```

Comment: using scala is not an option for me. because i am comparing some other libraries in java too. and especially because its kind of a home work problem and java is enforced.