# Scala api and java compatibility, do you have to remap?

Tags: java, scala

Say I have a scala library that exposes api methods that take scala specific types (say a collection that isn't available in java).

Does this mean you have to either change the exposed parameter, or change the collection to a java compatible type and then iterate over it and initialize the scala specific collection?

Basically what I am getting at is, when designing a scala api that will be used in java, you have to use a compatible type or you pay performance/memory penalty if you have to iterate and map the java collection to the scala one right?

Is that basically what the options are?

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.scala-lang.org/faq/4

> What does it mean that Scala is compatible with Java?
>
> The standard Scala backend is a Java VM. Scala classes are Java classes, and vice
> versa. You can call the methods of either language from methods in the
> other one. You can extend Java classes in Scala, and vice versa. The
> main limitation is that some Scala features do not have equivalents in
> Java, for example traits.

Also, to answer your question, plase visit [How to use scala.collection.immutable.List in a Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578615/how-to-use-scala-collection-immutable-list-in-a-java-code)