# Using the Scala collections (immutable) from Java

Tags: java, scala-collections

Is it possible to use the Scala immutable collections (HashMap, List, Vector, etc.) from Java code? I realize that some of the method names may end up looking "funny" and contain "$".

I have a legacy application written in Java. I cannot convert the code at this time, but I would like to use the immutable data structures to improve concurrency (multiple reads for every write).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to put scala-library.jar in the classpath.  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578615/how-to-use-scala-collection-immutable-list-in-a-java-code) for an example using Scala immutable lists in Java

As an alternative, Clojure also offers persistent data structures e.g. a [PersistentHashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.clojure/clojure/1.5.0-beta8/clojure/lang/PersistentHashMap.java) that come with Java source code, so your method names won't look as odd